# Looping Through An Array, Putting Each Index On A New Line, And Displaying End Result In An Alert

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am attempting to loop through a dynamic length array, all the while taking the value of each index object and putting it on a new line, with the end "goal", I guess, of displaying the end result in an alert. Really the alert part is just to make sure it is working correctly, but still. I also want to sort the values in ascending alphabetical order in the end result. I plan on sorting first, then loop through, as I assumed this would be easier.

Here is my code currently:

```
            var mainArr = [];
            var temp = "";
            do {
                temp = prompt("Enter Something... blah blah blah\n\nOr Enter The Number Zero When You Are Done");
                if (temp == 0) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    mainArr.push(temp);
                }
            } while (1);
            mainArr.sort()
            arrLen = mainArr.length
            for (var i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) {
                mainArr[i] = mainArr[i] + "<br />";
                return mainArr
            }
            alert(mainArr);
```

Currently nothing happens when I enter values into the prompt and finish by entering 0. Meaning when I enter 0, there is no alert. So I know I am missing something here or I am coding something wrong, though I am still fairly new at JS, so I am not sure what is going on here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also if this is a duplicate, please let me know and point me in the right direction. I Googled about a dozen different things to try and find something, but I didn't find anything that quite matched what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning from the loop making alert statement unreachable. You could simply use `mainArr.join('\n')` instead

```js
var mainArr = [];
var temp = "";
do {
  temp = prompt("Enter Something... blah blah blah\n\nOr Enter The Number Zero When You Are Done");
  if (temp == 0) {
    break;
  } else {
    mainArr.push(temp);
  }
} while (1);
mainArr.sort()
alert(mainArr.join('\n'));
```

Comment: @Dev-MDW2 Glad I could help.